# "Edit your answer draft" text being cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version: 1.0.26

If you start to answer a question, but don't finish it and navigate away from the question. If you go to the question again you get asked "Edit your answer draft", but the bottom of the text is cut off (picture below).

[image]

Comment: Still haven't checked those ColorNote notifications, I see? ;) I can't reproduce this on a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3. Perhaps it's tablet specific.

Comment: Haha I have another half dozen notifications that aren't show...the joys of not having much time :O   I think it is tablet specific, I looked at it on my phone and it doesn't display like that (grant if I turn my phone horizontal, then the "Edit your draft" option doesn't show up at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.27. I also fixed an issue with the text size of those being way too small, and the "X" icon on the right getting smaller the higher density the device was.